# php email - email is not getting sent

Tags: php, email

Till yesterday below code was working. not sure, today below code is not working. I am not getting any email. Though, I am getting echo as **right**, but I am not getting any email.

```
$to = "yyyyy@yahoo.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "xxxxx@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo "right";
} else {
    echo "wrong";
}
```

Any reason why this is happening?

---

I added `print phpinfo();` and check for sendmail_path. I found below.

`sendmail_path  /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`

---

### Answer

It was server problem. Hence email was not getting sent.

Comment: This is related to your host...

Comment: Nope, the code is clean.

Comment: Check your mail log as if mail returns true then the php is working fine.

Comment: Tell me which server u use and ur OS, i'll give u the answer, i faced this before!!

Comment: @FahimParkar just tell me ur Operating system (Windows, Ubuntu etc) and ur server(Apache, IIS etc.) i'll answer!!

Comment: as the others have said you will need access to your mail logs. it is possible that you are on shared hosting and the server is now blacklisted, etc.  thus causing your email to either bounce/be discarded.  Make sure you set the from to be an address you receive to check for bounces..

Comment: @tenstar : Ubuntu, Apache...

Comment: @FahimParkar brilliant, i had the same problem, wait i'll answer!

Comment: Yes i answered, just give it a shot! @FahimParkar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem in Ubuntu, Apache. You have to make sure that you have a mail sending software installed in your computer!

in ubuntu, open terminal and type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

after that try again!

Comment: I meant from server I can send and receive emails... means mail sending software is installed and hence I am able to send and receive emails.. but only for above code its not working... I will try and see what happens...

Comment: everything is correct.. the problem is in my code... I will post another question...

Comment: i posted an answer to that question too, if it works accept it bro!

Comment: check my new answer to your new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675222/php-params-not-getting-called/17675258#17675258 @FahimParkar

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand the email is sent from the PHP mail() function. This function uses the local MTA to deliver the message.

If you  have control over the server and its MTA you can start checking the logfiles of the server. There you should see the email from the PHP mail() function showing up. If this is not the case PHP seems to not pass it on to the MTA (in your case sendmail).

If it shows up in the logs, check the lines for more details. The reason can be in there. If you are not sure, post the log content (do not forget to mask private details of it).

But if it does not show any problems in the logs there could be a couple of other reasons. Like your IP to be blacklisted. To check that visit the following website [http://mxtoolbox.com](http://mxtoolbox.com/). But it would be possible as well that the receiving email server is bouncing the email back ... which would show up in the servers root inbox where you could see the return reason in it.

I hope that was helpfull for you!?

Answer (score 0):

There is no PHP error here, it is a problem with your server setup. PHP will return true on mail() once the mail has been send off to sendmail, or whatever you are using. It does not know whether the email has actually been sent or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$message = "test 1\r\ntest 2\r\ntest 3";

$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

mail(SETYOURMAIL@MAIL.COM', 'My Subject', $message);
```

if this does not work check the php.ini

http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Some time mail() function may not work, so you should use PHPMailer, A well written documentation is written here :

[rohitashv.wordpress.com/2013/01/19/how-to-send-mail-using-php/](http://rohitashv.wordpress.com/2013/01/19/how-to-send-mail-using-php/)