# php params not getting called

Tags: php, param

I have link as `test.php?fullname=Fahim&emailid=test@test.com`

In test.php I have below

```
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$emailid = $_POST['emailid'];

echo "$fullname===$emailid===";
```

I always get response as `======`

I was expecting as `Fahim===test@test.com`.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: That's `$_GET` not `$_POST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In test.php data will be recieved using $_GET cause you are sending data using URL

Comment: earlier everything was working.. all of sudden dnt know today problem is coming...

Comment: $_POST will only work if the data is POSTed to the script, putting it in the URL is not POST, so perhaps you used to use a form to submit the information

Comment: you have to first check also that your form method is GET only

Answer (score 1):

Your link `test.php?fullname=Fahim&emailid=test@test.com`

```
$fullname = $_GET['fullname'];
$emailid = $_GET['emailid'];
echo "$fullname===$emailid===";
```

Output

```
Fahim===test@test.com
```

You have to use `$_GET['param_name']` to retrive values sending via url.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass parameters from the url, it is a get request..

In PHP, we use `$_GET` for fetching information from get request

```
$fullname = $_GET['fullname'];
$emailid = $_GET['emailid'];

echo "$fullname===$emailid===";
```